# Why is VoiceOver on Chrome reading everything inside of a DIV?

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility, voiceover

I've run into the following issue on Chrome (v. 85.0.4183.102) on macOS (10.15.5):

Occasionally, when I select a div using VoiceOver, it will read out everything contained in the div. For instance, a `div` with `role="main"` might have a header, a few paragraphs, and some links. VoiceOver will read out *all* of those items when the parent `div` is selected. I can then press <kbd>VO Next</kbd> to advance to the first element within the parent `div` and it will read that item out individually.

I cannot reproduce this in Safari. When I select the main `div`, it simply reads "main". I can press VO Next and it will read out the elements individually, as one would expect.

Any idea why VO is doing this only in Chrome?

Comment: Is this only limited to what you're specifically developing, or an issue that is replicated across other websites also?

Comment: @ShannonYoung I have not been able to test this on other sites. In the end, we decided to chock this up to how VoiceOver works with Chrome. Since it's not a blocker for our assistive device users and more of an inconvenience, we've decided to address this later down the line and see if future versions of Chrome solve this issue.

Comment: Apple optimise VO to work with Safari. If it works with Chrome, it's largely by accident.